# How to put a variable in text file?

Tags: python

So i'm trying to insert a variable inside a text file and i've defined them as shown below:

```
 for filename in os.listdir("/home/gyanender/Desktop/s1d_gyanender"):
    if filename.endswith("_s1d_A.fits"):

      df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(SN_dic,orient='index')
      df = df.mean()  
      out_name = s1d_header['OBJECT'] +'-' + s1d_header['DATE-OBS'] +'.ares'

      mine_opt =  '/home/gyanender/bin/ARES/mine.opt'
      file_opt=open(mine_opt,'w')
      file_opt.writelines(("specfits=filename","\n","fileout=out_name","\n","rejt=df"))
      file_opt.close()
```

So in the end what i got is something like this, i got name of the variables in the text but what i want is the values of those variables in my text file as i've to give that file as an input to another code.

```
specfits='filename'
fileout='out_name'
rejt=df
```

As

```
filename = HARPS.2016-04-01T09:44:43.034_s1d_A.fits
out_name = Moon-2016-04-01T09:44:43.034.ares
rejt = 166.6 (As the values of df is 166.6)
```

So my ideal file should look like something like this:

```
specfits='HARPS.2016-04-01T09:44:43.034_s1d_A.fits'
fileout='Moon-2016-04-01T09:44:43.034.ares'
rejt= 166.6
```

So can someone tell me where i'm making the mistake?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're doing

```
file_opt.writelines(("specfits=filename","\n","fileout=out_name","\n","rejt=df"))
```

Note that you're actually printing the string `"specfits=filename"` to a the file. There's nothing here to tell the code that that's not what you want it to print.

I think what you want is to *substitute* the variable name for the variable itself. This can be done using string formatting. Assuming python 3:

```
file_opt.writelines(("specfits={}".format(filename), "\n", "fileout={}".format(out_name), "\n", "rejt={}".format(df)))
```

Here, the `{}` in your string is replaced by whatever you give as an argument to the `format()` function.

If you want single-quotes around the values you can just put them in the string you're printing out, e.g. `"specfits='{}'"`

Comment: what if want to put two values in the format like "rvmask='{}'".format(0,df) . I tried to do that and it gave the error? @Greencloakguy

Comment: Multiple instances of `{}`, e.g. `"rvmask='{}{}'".format(0,df)`. They will be filled in order of appearance. Alternatively, you can put numbers inside the curly brackets, which correspond to which parameter to `format()` you want to replace: `"rvmask='{0}{1}'".format(0, df)` would replace `{0}` with 0 and `{1}` with the value of `df`.

Comment: yep it worked but you forget to mention one small thing. it should be this "rvmask='{0},{1}'".format(0, df). Thanks alot for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Don't try to invent the wheel, choose some storage method and use it.

This example uses json:

```
import json
data = {   # create a dict with the data
   'specfits': specfits,
   'fileout':  fileout,
   'rejt':  rejt,
}

with open(mine_opt, 'w') as file_opt:
    json.dump(data, file_opt)
```

Then reading it will be very easy!

```
with open(mine_opt) as file_opt:
    data = json.load(file_opt)

print(data['specfits']) # will print HARPS.2016-04-01T09:44:43.034_s1d_A.fits
```